# Using CONVERT_TZ causes Perfomance issues?

Tags: mysql, sql

We are planning if either to change the timezone of the whole database or using CONVERT_TZ in all our functions and events.

Is there any perfomance issues is we decide to use CONVERT_TZ having in mind it could be converting and comparing millions of rows and events every minute?

Comment: For once **any** function will have great impact if you are joining by a column that is transformed. It will negate the use of indexes.

Comment: But, in essence, you need to assess why are you transforming the data in the first place. If you are doing so so frequently, maybe you should store the timestamps without the time zone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends *where* you plan to use the `CONVERT_TZ` function.

For example, if it's wrapped around a column in a `WHERE` clause, that will disable MySQL ability to use an index range scan operation. And that could have significant performance implications, or cause "performance issues".

For example, if this query is making use an index range scan on an index with `mydatetime` as the leading column, picking just a few needles out of a big haystack:

```
 SELECT t.foo
   FROM my_huge_table t
  WHERE t.mydatetime >= '2018-10-09 14:30'
    AND t.mydatetime <  '2018-10-09 15:15'
```

Adding `CONVERT_TZ` function around the *literals* won't cause performance issues. The performance will be the same:

```
 SELECT t.foo
   FROM my_huge_table t
  WHERE t.mydatetime >= CONVERT_TZ('2018-10-09 08:30','EST5EDT','UTC')
    AND t.mydatetime <  CONVERT_TZ('2018-10-09 09:15','EST5EDT','UTC')
```

But if we wrap the columns in the WHERE clause in a function, that will force MySQL to evaluate the function and then do the comparison, and it's going to do that for *every* row in the table.

*Do **NOT** do this:*

```
 SELECT t.foo
   FROM my_huge_table t
  WHERE CONVERT_TZ(t.mydatetime,'UTC','EST5EDT') >= '2018-10-09 08:30'
    AND CONVERT_TZ(t.mydatetime,'UTC','EST5EDT') <  '2018-10-09 09:15'
```

---

As long as the SQL still references *bare* columns in the predicates (conditions in the WHERE clause and ON clause), then adding `CONVERT_TZ` functions in other places in the SQL shouldn't cause a significant performance impact.